# Using multiple classes within other classes

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm finishing up a C++ assignment and I'm running into an issue with connecting all the classes together. The classes have basic constructors, getters, setters, etc. so I'm confident the abundance of compiler errors I'm getting are due to me mix and matching all of my Classes incorrectly...

My classes are split up into cpp and h files and I've basically used the include statements every time that class needs something from another class. A basic diagram of which class needs what is shown below:

[image]

Basically what I'm trying to figure out is if having #include "Product.h" in both CustomerOrder and Retailer is messing things up or if I'm doing this all the wrong way.

Any help would be lovely!
Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's one instance of what each class is basically doing. The Customer class holds an array of CustomerOrders and CustomerOrders holds an array of Products etc. etc..

```
...
class Customer
{
private:
    string customerName;
    string customerID;
    float balance;
    static const int ORDERSIZE = 2;
    CustomerOrder* orderList[ORDERSIZE];
    Retailer retailer;
...
```

and Customer Order:

```
...
class CustomerOrder
{
private:
    static const int SHOPSIZE = 20;
    Product* shoppingList[SHOPSIZE];
...
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal amount of code to represent how you have your classes set up in your project?  You don't have to post everything, we just need to see how you have them "mix and matching".  Also, are you using header guards?

Comment: We'll need errors generated too, or at least a good description of what is wrong.

Comment: Including "Product.h" in both CustomerOrder and Retailer won't mess things up. If it does, make sure that you haven't forgotten the include guards.

Comment: Sure! I'll post a small snippet of how I'm using my code in just a second!

Comment: @user3224853: You should use standard containers, not arrays! For example, std::vector<CustomerOrder>. std::vector is considered the default collection mechanism in C++, *not* arrays. This will help you get rid of all the serious problems associated with arrays, too many to list them all in a single comment...! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your diagram is confusing. In OOP, arrows like the one you use indicate public inheritance, but that doesn't seem to be the case here (nor that it should).

Your question cannot be answered generally. You `#include` another class if you need the complete type. Otherwise, a **forward declaration** will do. That only has an impact on compilation speed. Nevertheless, the rule is to *use forward declarations if you can and `#include`s if you must*.

Here are some cases where you can get away with a forward declaration:

1.) Pointers:

```
class AnotherClass; // <-- forward declaration
class Example
{
    // ...
    AnotherClass *another_class;
};
```

2.) References:

```
class AnotherClass; // <-- forward declaration
class Example
{
    // ...
    void f(AnotherClass &another_class);
};
```

3.) Return values:

```
class AnotherClass; // <-- forward declaration
class Example
{
    // ...
    AnotherClass Get();
};
```

As soon as you are actually using the object of the forward-declared class, you need to have the `#include`. If you forget, the compiler will remind you.

Caveat 1: Pay attention when you use forward-declared (i.e. so-called "incomplete") types in standard containers. Your compiler may allow this, but it's undefined behaviour to do so!

```
class Example; // forward declaration
std::vector<Example> v; // undefined behaviour!
```

Caveat 2: Don't attempt to forward-declare standard classes. Just do `#include <vector>`, `#include <string>` and so on and let the compiler figure out how to optimize compile time.

Edit: Actually, the *linker*, rather than the compiler, will remind you if you forget to include a forward-declared class you cannot forward-declare, but that's just a nitpick :)

Comment: Ahhhhh! This is really informative, thanks! I actually discovered that when doing my header guards I labelled them all as PRODUCT_H which may have lead to many issues... I'm editing an example of how I'm using the classes in the main post and I'll cross reference with what you're saying. Thanks!